# Detecting currency values in a line using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

In the following lines how to write regular expression to find whether a line startswith currency or ends with currency

```
line = ["$20 is your bill",
        "this is your bill",
        "bill amount is $30",
        "$40 or $50"]

for l in line:
    matchObj = re.search( r'\$[\d.]+', l, re.M|re.I)
```

How to check if a line starts or ends with a currency?

Comment: Your regexp works on the example data. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @LennartRegebro: it does not work for the third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\$\d+.*|.*\$\d+$
```

seems to be working for me.

This won't work if the currency isn't an integer value, though.

Comment: Why so complicated? `^\$\d|\$\d+$` does the same. And this is trivial to extend to non-integral values: `^\$\d|\$[\d.,]+$`